# Google Chart not working when using apex:tabPanel

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

If I have an `apex:tabPanel` in a page where I'm using Google Visualization, the browser crashes. Any one has a work around?

Tried with Google Chrome and FireFox.

Here's the code to see what I mean (uncomment to get the browser crash):

```
<apex:page >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var barGraphData = [
    ["Title", "Ratings"],
    ["Title 1", 4.0],
    ["Title 2", 5.0],
    ["Title 3", 3.5]
];
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(barGraphData);

        var options = {
            title: 'Title'
        };
        var div = document.getElementById("chart_div");
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(div);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
<!-- uncomment  to get the error
        <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" id="theTab">
    </apex:tabPanel>
-->
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px; height: 250px;"></div>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Try Visualforce Charting?

Comment: Yes, ended up using Visualforce Chart. Was surprised to see that it doesn't support render as PDF...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend submitting a case for this one. I noticed that the same problem happens when you use a panelBar as well. But other VF components such as pageBlock seem to work fine.

This appears to be a serious issue between the Google jsapi and certain Visualforce components. The complete browser lockup that happens could be some sort of endless wait state or loop. Nothing obvious is showing itself in the Chrome debugger.

I'll be interested to see if this issue gets resolved and what the root cause is. For now I'd consider implementing a JS [alternative](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) to apex:tabPanel.

Good luck.

Comment: Added the problem as Idea:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kx4rAAA